# Webkit filter as a text or box-shadow

Tags: css, webkit

Is there any way to get a text shadow or a box shadow that behaves similar to how a `-webkit-filter:saturate(50%);` (or `brightness(80%);`) would look over the entire selector?  Basically, I need whatever the shadow falls on to be saturated/desaturated.

Why?  I'm putting text over an image, and I think it would be a cool effect to either blur or desaturate the space around the text.  In the end, the effect would look something like this:

[image]

That's not a white text-shadow, it's basically a text shadow with a blending mode of "Color Dodge", which accomplishes the effect I'm after.  Any way I can do this in CSS?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution might involve a combination of `-webkit-filter: blur()` and pseudo-elements. For example: [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OZONOM/2)

This could also be combined with any text-shadowing given. Not sure if that resolves the issue perfectly, because the effects on the text aren't really evaluating the background colors, but it might work for your purpose. Interesting challenge, and would be a useful feature to have built-in to css.